# How does sklearn calculate accuracy on the validation set when XGBoost is given class weights?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, xgboost, imbalanced-data, xgbclassifier

I am using XGBoost's [sklearn API](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/stable/python/python_api.html#module-xgboost.sklearn) with sklearn's `RandomizedSearchCV()` to train a boosted tree model with cross validation. My problem is imbalanced, so I've supplied the `scale_pos_weight` parameter to my `XGBClassifier`. For simplicity, let's say that I'm doing cross validation with two folds (k = 2). At the end of this post, I've provided an example of the model I'm fitting.

How is accuracy (or any metric) calculated on the validation set? Is the accuracy weighted using the `scale_pos_weights` argument given to XGBoost, or does sklearn calculate the unweighted accuracy?

```py
import xgboost as xgb
from sklearn.model_selection import RandomForestClassifier

xgb_estimator = xgb.XGBClassifier(booster = "gbtree")

tune_grid = {"scale_pos_weight": [1, 10, 100],  "max_depth": [1, 5, 10]} # simple hyperparameters as example.

xgb_seearch = RandomizedSearchCV(xgb_estimator, tune_grid, cv=2, n_iter = 10, 
                                 scoring = "accuracy", refit = True, 
                                 return_train_score = True)

results = xgb_search.fit(X, y)
results.cv_results # look at cross validation metrics
```

Answer (score 0):

> Does sklearn calculate the unweighted accuracy?

`scikit-learn` will select for the model maximizing the `scoring` parameter. When `"accuracy"` is provided, it will return unweighted accuracy—which is usually biased on imbalanced problems.

Pass `scoring="balanced_accuracy"` to compute the weighted version.